# Why does the for create an infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying out coding and made this little hangman game for fun

```
from random import randint
import sys

used_letters = []
life = 3

wordList = ['apple','bee','castle','house','train','computer','snake','program','cellphone','microphone']
word = wordList[randint(0,(len(wordList)-1))]
wordList = [letter for letter in word]
amountLetters = 0
word_holder = []

for letter in wordList:
    word_holder.append(amountLetters)
    amountLetters += 1


while life > 0:
    fail_counter = 0
    user_input = (input('What is your guess?')).lower()
    if user_input == word:
        print('You win')
        sys.exit(0)
    elif user_input == 'word':
        print(word_holder)
    elif user_input == 'letters':
        print(used_letters)
    elif wordList.count(user_input) > 0:
        for letter in wordList:
            if user_input == letter:
                indexNb = wordList.index(letter)
                word_holder.insert(indexNb, letter)
                wordList.insert(indexNb, '0')
                print(f'You found the letter {letter}')
    else:
        fail_counter = fail_counter + 1
        if fail_counter == len(wordList):
            print('You lost a life')
            used_letters.append(letter)
            life -= 1

if life == 0:
    print('You lose!')
```

I've been trying different ways to make for in the while work but I couldn't. This seems like a good way but it keeps getting into an infinite loop, repeating the print with the same letter. So basically I'm wondering why is the 'for' going into an infinite loop although 'letter' in 'wordList' should be finite.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. However, you should make your question more explicit. What exactly are you asking us? Are you asking for a change in your code so the loop is no longer infinite?

Comment: well i'm wondering why is the 'for' going into an infinite loop, altough letter in wordList is finite. and i taking any kind of comment or help haha

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `insert`ing into `wordList` at the index you're currently examining, which means you push out the `letter` you're checking by one (putting a `'0'` in its current location), meaning it's found again on the next loop.

So on the first loop, searching for `'x'` in `['x', 'y', 'z']`, you find `x` at index `0`, and then `insert` `'0'` at that index, updating the `list` to `['0', 'x', 'y', 'z']`. On the next loop, it advances the internal index of the `list` iterator from 0 to 1, and puts the value found (`'x'` again!) in `letter`. Then it `insert`s `'0'` to get `['0', '0', 'x', 'y', 'z']`. I assume you can follow the logic from here; you'll `insert` an infinite number of `'0'`s because each one pushes your target out another index, and you immediately "find" it again.

Answer (score 0):

Empirically, `wordList` is *not* finite: you append to it while you're iterating through it, which extends the list.  Use a `print` statement within the loop to trace your values, and you'll see the problem.  You insert a `0` in front of the letter you found.  That letter gets bumped right one position, and you get to find the *same* letter on the next execution.

```
    for letter in wordList:
        if user_input == letter:
            indexNb = wordList.index(letter)
            word_holder.insert(indexNb, letter)
            wordList.insert(indexNb, '0')
            print('You found the letter', letter)
            print('   wordList is now', wordList)
```

Instead, use the `replace` method or build a new string from the original.  For instance, just replace this loop with

```
    wordList.replace(letter, '0')
    print('You found the letter', letter)
```

Also, please note a distinct problem: you're working on the entire `wordList`, rather than just one word; I haven't fixed that portion.

Comment: `wordList` is a `list`. There is no `replace` method on `list`s. Did you mean `wordList[indexNb] = '0'`?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow community. Following line in the for loop may be causing the infinite loop, please update your code.

```
wordList.insert(indexNb, '0')
```